# How to Show Rad Busy Indicator without Async Call

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, busyindicator

I have two function in my viewModel,  one of which brings data (say from Database which may take time depends on data and network ) and second method generate UI dynamically according to data. 
I want to show Busy Indicator on first function call ,  but i don't want it to be Async .
Is there any way to show RadBusyIndicator without  Async Call to the function, 
i tried to put the first function in thread and then put the main thread on waiting for the working thread thread, but it doesn't work for me .

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the long running Data fetch operation to happen on a different thread than the UI one. Then only way I can think of is to have a separate Window with waiting/busy indicator. And create this window instance and show it from a separate thread.

Close the window & thread when the Data Fetch completes. So you are going to need quiet some multi-thread sync & communication.